# Cannot infer type for type parameter 'T'

Tags: rust, types, traits, generics

I have a function using the following 2 types:

```
pub type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
pub type AccountIdOf<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
```

and I use them to implement a method in a struct using generics:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Encode, Decode)]
pub struct Investor<T,U>{
    pub account_id:T,
    pub nft:U,
}

impl<T:pallet::Config,U> Investor<T,U>{
    
    pub fn contribute(origin:OriginFor<T>,acc:AccountIdOf<T> ,value:BalanceOf<T>) -> DispatchResult{
        let c1=Contribution::new(&acc,&value);
        let _who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        let _now = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
        if ContributionsLog::<T>::contains_key(c1.account){
            ContributionsLog::<T>::mutate(c1.account, |val|{
                *val += *c1.amount;
            })
        } else {
            ContributionsLog::<T>::insert(&acc,value);
            ContAccounts::<T>::mutate(|val|{
                val.push(acc);
            })
        }
        
        //function taking contribution storage and amount as inputs here
        Ok(().into())
    }
}
```

the problem is when I try to call the contribute method as below

```
Investor::contribute(who,dev.account_id,rent);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot infer type for type parameter 'T'

how/where should I define an explicit type for T?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than call `Investor::contribute(who,dev.account_id,rent);`

Seems you should call:

```
Investor::<T::AccountId, u32>::contribute(who,dev.account_id,rent);
```

And just be explicit with your type definitions of the generics when accessing the `contribute` function.

Comment: Thank you! I have a follow up question: let's say that I call the contribute method inside a function that has the following parameters :  `fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, something: u32, acc:T::AccountId ,rent:BalanceOf<T>,cd:CID,prop:Properties,start:Option<BlockNumberOf<T>>,end:Option<BlockNumberOf<T>>) -> DispatchResult `Rust considers that T is a `frame_system::Config>::AccountId ` and therefore does not have the right T to correctly define  for example `let _who = ensure_signed(origin)?;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you open a new question with a bit more clarity?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think a look a the full code will make it clear: https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/blob/structure_template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs On the branch "structure_template" the line 144 when uncommented prevents me from using OriginOf. This line is calling the method "contribute" mentioned earlier.

Comment: In that case, It should be `Investor::<T::AccountId, u32>::contribute(who,dev.account_id,rent);`, or `pub account_id:T::AccountId,`